# changing months dataframe values using dict

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, data-cleaning

I have trouble using dict to replace values in a dataframe.

```
    m= { 'january': 1, 'february': 2, 'march': 3, 'april': 4, 'may': 5,'june': 6,'july': 7,
'august': 8, 'september': 9, 'october': 10, 'november': 11, 'december': 12}

df = pd.DataFrame({'place': {0: 'canada', 1: 'canada', 2: 'the united states'}, 'time': {0:  'february 11, 2018', 1: 'december 9, 2017', 2: 'january 18, 2018'}})

   place                      time
0  canada              february 11, 2018
1  canada              december 9, 2017
2  the united states   january 18, 2018
```

I want to only change the month names to the  and I had tried .replace and .map methods but not thing changes

```
dftp2.replace({'time': m })
dftp2['time'].map(m)
```

did I do something wrong or are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.dt.strftime()` to convert dates:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%-m %d, %Y')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               place         time
0             canada   2 11, 2018
1             canada  12 09, 2017
2  the united states   1 18, 2018
```